# Change Keycloak RestAPI URLs

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api

I am using Keycloak 21.0.2. I was wondering if I could change the URI of RestAPIs. For example instead of:

```
http://KEYCLOAK_URL/realms/{REALM_NAME}/protocol/openid-connect/token
```

having:

```
http://KEYCLOAK_URL/{REALM_NAME}/oicd/token
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated.